# Coordinates of small boxes

Tags: geometry, algorithms, coordinate-systems

I have the screen for different users like this:

[image]

In each screen there are small boxes each for a user. I have calculated width and height of each small box for different number users.

But now I am not getting how to get the coordinates of the boxes(top left point of the box).

The coordinate system starts from top-left of the screen that is the top left of the screen has coordinates as (0,0)

Can someone please help me out in this.

Sorry, my image is not displaying. I think it is because I dont have enought reps

Comment: Sorry, my image is not displaying. I think it is because I dont have enought reps.

Comment: Actually, I realised now that the number of smaller screens is not always a square number. What is the rule for how many smaller screens there are, as a function of $n_{\text{users}}$ ?

Comment: @MattiP. Why we need a rule for that?

Comment: Ah, so you want to calculate the coordinates, knowing the width and height of each smaller screen (instead of the number of users)?

Comment: I believe that you can calculate it yourself :) What are the coordinates of the top-left corner of user number 1? Well, $(0,0)$ of course. How about user number 2 ? Etc etc ...

Comment: @MattiP. I have still doubts like for user 3 the x coordinate is again 0 when number of small boxes are 3 or 4. But when number of boxes are from 5 to 9 then x coordinate of user 3 is (width of small screen) * 2

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we know the dimensions of the large screen (width $W$, height $H$) and how many smaller screens there are in each direction (for example, for two users, we have a $2 \times 1$-grid). Let the number of screens in the $x$-direction be $n$ and the number of screens in the $y$-direction be $m$. So these are all the numbers that we know in the beginning.

The next step is to realize that the coordinates of the top-left corner of each of the smaller screens are multiples of $\frac{W}{n}$ and $\frac{H}{m}$. In other words, there are integers $a$ and $b$ so that the coordinates for each of these points is of the form
$$
(x,y) = \left(a\cdot \frac{W}{n} ,~ b\cdot \frac{H}{m}\right)
$$
The next question is, what are these multipliers $a$ and $b$ ? We can take a test case and just see if we see a pattern. Let's assume that we have eight users and then $n=m=3$. Then, for each of the users (we start numerating the user number $u$ from 0, so the "first" user has $u=0$), the multipliers are the following:

1. First user: $u= 0 \Rightarrow (a,b)= (0,0)$
2. $u= 1 \Rightarrow (1,0)$
3. $u= 2 \Rightarrow (2,0)$
4. $u= 3 \Rightarrow (0,1)$
5. $u= 4 \Rightarrow (1,1)$
6. $u= 5 \Rightarrow (2,1)$
7. $u= 6 \Rightarrow (0,2)$
8. $u= 7 \Rightarrow (1,2)$

Can you see the pattern here? It's really easy to see that, for the "$u+1$":th user,
$$
\begin{cases}
a = u \mod n \\
b = \lfloor \frac{u}{n} \rfloor
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $\text{mod}$ refers to taking the remainder in division, and $\lfloor ... \rfloor$ is the floor function. I think we're done here.